# Can't boot WINDOWS 10 from SSD in hp probook 450 g3

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I am trying to go from HDD to SSD so I cloned boot disk to SSD. Although I have changed the boot order and checked other boot options as 'disabled', it keeps booting from HDD.
[Boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4tX1.jpg)

[Bios Setup -> Boot Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu7A5.jpg)

Comment: Try removing the hard drive and boot with only the SSD drive in place. Windows 10 still may see the activation on the hard drive if it is installed.

Comment: Is the SSD bootable? What OS is on it?

Comment: How did you do the cloning? Most probably the SSD is not bootable.